# HTML anchor tag takes entire line

Tags: html, css

I have the following html markup:

```html
<a href="">First Link</a> / <a href="">Second Link</a> / <a href="">Third Link</a>
```

I want it to display as:

```
First Link / Second Link / Third Link
```

But what I get is:

```
First Link
/
Second Link
/
Third Link
```

And links can be clickable in any place of their row. How can I fix it? I tried "display: block;", but it didn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regular anchor Tags are inline elements. You have to check if in your CSS, you already assign anchors globally to a block element. `a { display: block;}`

For fast fix:
Wrap your code anchor line (`Breadcrumbs`) in a container and assign with a unique id or class Name. Then you can assign only for this line the anchors to a inline element.

```css
a {
 display: block;
}
.anchor-regular a {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<a href="">test block </a> <a href="">test block</a>
<div class="anchor-regular">
<a href="">First Link</a> / <a href="">Second Link</a> / <a href="">Third Link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Anchor tags (`a`) behave like you want by default. What you are getting means that somewhere in your code, there is a `display:block`, `display:flex`, or `display:grid` applied to them. You could overwrite this with a `display:inline`, like so:

```css
a {
 display:inline;
}
```

```html
<a href="">First Link</a> / <a href="">Second Link</a> / <a href="">Third Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<a>` element is not supposed to be used like you are doing here. `<a>` is an inline element - which means that it goes with the "flow" of other elements and it does not have a width and height of its own. In other words, it's supposed to be used like a "wrapper" around other elements.

So instead of this:

```
<a>I'm a link</a>
```

This is a better idea:

```
<p><a>I'm a link</a></p>
```

and then in your styling, you actually style the `<p>` tag and not the `<a>`.

In your case, you have a group of links(a breadcrumb, by the looks of it) which you want to represent using links. So you could do something like this:

```
<ul class="mybreadcrumb">
  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a>First</a></li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a>Second</a></li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a>Third</a></li>
</ul>
```

And then in your CSS:

```
ul.mybreadcrumb {
  list-style: none;
}

ul.mybreadcrumb li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.mybreadcrumb li+li:before {
  content: ' / ';
}
```

That `+` is a sibling selector - so it'll add a `/` before the second and onward `li` element.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the `a` tag only affect its content, do this:

```
a {
    width: fit-content;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Your answer is false, you'll want to see how the `<a>` tag behaves by default here: [W3Schools Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.php). And notice that the `<a>` tag does not have `display: block;` like the `<p>` tag does, which is what makes the `<p>` tag *not* `display: inline`.

Comment: Okay, my bad @RobertBradley. This is what worked for me though back then. Everyone has different scenarios.